# Bar titles labeled with values in R-base

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way of indicate the real value for each bar appearing in the image when a bar plot is created using R-base? 
For instance, using the iris dataset:

```
barplot(table(iris$Species))
```

Could show in the top of each bar the value “50”, indicating the exact amount of the species?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graphics.off()
d = table(iris$Species)
b = barplot(d)    # so that x-axis values will be stored in 'b'
par(xpd = TRUE)   # so that text can be added outside plot region
text(x = b, y = d + 5, labels = d)  # also test `labels = paste(names(d), d, sep = "\n")`
```